# Alternative to Change data capture

Tags: streaming-api, change-data-capture, cometd, streaming

Since Change data capture event (CDC) is a paid add-on after 5 objects, what alternatives we have to get notified about change in salesforce object ?

Comment: Do you have a budget on how much you want to spend on this?

Comment: Your own, custom change detection and notification solution. See [Data Integration](https://architect.salesforce.com/decision-guides/data-integration) and [Event-Driven](https://architect.salesforce.com/decision-guides/event-driven) architecture decision guides for more info.

Comment: @NickCook: We dont want incur any new cost. But we want to be notified about changes made to all the objects

Comment: So you want more features, but you do not want to pay to buy nor build them. I don't think there is a free alternative here.